# Passing parameters to callback function without changing method (Siesta Testing namespace)

Tags: javascript, callback, integration-testing, siesta

Does anyone know how to pass parameters to a callback function that you cannot alter?

So here is the code I'm trying to implement (It is a siesta testing method):

Base.js:

```
waitForComponentQueryVisible: function (parentNext, parameters) {

    var th = this,
    query = parameters.query,
    scope = th,
    callback = callFunct,
    timeout = 10000;
//The function inside here (returnToParentTester(parentNext, parameters)) is from Base.js 
    callFunct = function () {
        scope.returnToParentTester(parentNext);
    }
    this.test.waitForComponentQueryVisible(query, callback, scope, timeout);
},
```

The problem here is of two parts: 
1. I cant get the scope just right so I can use the returnToParentTester method that is found in Base.js
2. I want to pass in parentNext into the method but cannot do that when defining it as a callback

this is the method I need to run as the callback:

Base.js:

```
returnToParentTester: function (parentNext, parameters) {
    debugger;
    if (parentNext) {
        parentNext.call(undefined, parameters);
    } else {
        this.test.fail('--Developer Error-- undefined parentNext ' +
                       'variable. All the chains are going to fail');
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't get the scope just right so I can use the returnToParentTester method that is found in Base.js

Use the `call` method to change the scope:

```
Base.returnToParentTester.call(myScope)
```

> I want to pass in parentNext into the method but cannot do that when defining it as a callback

Use an anonymous function as a callback and pass parameters within its scope:

```
$("body").click(function(e){foo(e.target,bar,baz)})
```

then let it do the work:

```
function foo(myScope, next1, param1)
 {
 Base.returnToParentTester.call(myScope, next1, param1)
 }
```

**References**

- [Fast JavaScript max/min](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)
- [Mixins and Constructor Functions](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/mixins-and-constructor-functions)
- [Function.prototype.apply revisited](http://hexmen.com/blog/2006/12/revisiting-functionprototypeapply-for-ie5/)
- [applyFunctionArguments - argument injection technique in JavaScript](http://www.angrycoding.com/2011/06/applyfunctionarguments-argument.html)
- [Functional JavaScript, Part 3: .apply(), .call(), and the arguments object](http://tech.pro/tutorial/2010/functional-javascript-part-3-apply-call-and-the-arguments-object)